# In MongoDB, is it better practice to give commonly queried objects their own referenced Schemas, or leave them in their parent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I'm new to Mongo and although this seems like a very common thing to do, I can't find a clear "best" solution in the docs. Here is my setup:

I am building a shared todo list app which allows a user to add other users to their todos. I am setting it up with 3 main schemas:

1. User (profile data and login info),
2. TodoList (array of `TodoItem`s and an array `User`s are subscribed to it)
3. TodoItem (meta data and comments)

   ```
   var User = new mongoose.Schema({
       username: { type:String, required:true , unique:true},
       password: {type:String, required:true},
       memberOfAccounts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Account"}]
   });

   var TodoList = new mongoose.Schema({
       todos: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "TodoItem"}],
       subscribers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}],
       title: {type: String}
   });

   var TodoItem = new mongoose.Schema({
       parentList:Id {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "TodoList"},
       text: [{type: String}],
       completed: {type: Boolean},
       comments: [{
           text: {type: String},
           author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}
       }]
   });
   ```

A `User` can be subscribed to many `TodoLists`s (many-to-many), while a `TodoItem` can only exist in one `TodoList`. Also, the comments for a `TodoItem` should be queried individually, as should  any other poperties of `TodoItem`.

Eventually I would like the `TodoItem` to be much more complex (start date, end date, ext. time, etc.), which would also make it the most active Document, which is why I gave it it's own Model to begin with. I'm realizing that this is maybe not the best way to structure it since it is still a one-to-many relationship, and perhaps new `TodoItems`s should just be pushed directly to the 'todos' array in the `TodoList` document.

**tl;dr:** Should I create deeply nested Schemas where the most commonly queried/written objects are the children, or should I create separate collections to be queried with references to those objects in the parents?

Comment: I realized while I was typing this out that in a database with lots of TodoItems, it would take much longer to search through the entire list for the items that match the requested parentListId, but I don't have anything to base that off of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded document vs reference in mongoose design model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302279/embedded-document-vs-reference-in-mongoose-design-model)

Comment: I'm not gonna mark it as a duplicate since I am unsure of that questions content to be honest (there are many questions on the topic with better content), instead I will just mention that the OP should Google around

Answer (score 0):

Commonly queried objects are better suited as parent documents. Depending on the extent/complexity of nesting, indexes will be less efficient as there is more to traverse.

Metadata, revisions and historical data can reside in child documents.