# From the SQL to the Mongo way of designing a DB

Tags: sql, mongodb

I want to understand how to solve certain issues on Mongo, I had been working with SQL for a while and I know the basics of DB design, many of those are useless in Mongo, since is completely different.

Here's an example. I have user credentials (username, password), user information (name, lastname, ...), and user facebook information (friend list, likes, ecc). In MySQL a good way to organize that is in 3 tables, one for credentials, one for general user information, and one for fb user information, all 3 related by the user ID. In that way if I need to login the user I need to query just the credentials table that have very light rows (3 columns; id, username, password).

Well, how this argument can be translated to the non relational realm? Do I extend my users object by adding the general info and the facebook info as arrays?:

```
user =>array(
              'username' => 'user1', 
              'password' => 'pass1',
              'gInfo'    => array('name' => '','lastname' => ''),
              'fbInfo'   => array('likes' => '','friends' => '')
)
```

Or like in SQL, its better if I created two new objects related by the Mongo _ID of the user.

Comment: Wouldn't your way of designing MySQL break 2/3NF? And yes you would normally just extend your user object to store all the data about a single enetity unless there was a peformance reason not to

Comment: I have noticed you have said: "In that way if I need to login the user I need to query just the credentials table that have very light rows" I doubt very much you are getting any performance from splitting up your tables (that applies to really high usage) infact you might be getting lower performance due to having to query more tables writing out more IO

Comment: Yeah, designing mongo db is really different from what you usually do with relational db. Looks lokie your question is a common one, should I embed or reference, take a look at my reply to this question, might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302279/embedded-document-vs-reference-in-mongoose-design-model/21317378#21317378

Comment: @MaksymStrukov I think this was covered in my answer outside of the FUD in the comments

Comment: @Neil what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your real case.

"Do my so called 'relations' exceed a reasonable amount of 'records' per user, and does it make sense to maintain that information in a separate 'relational' store?"

So if your answer to that is **no** then you are a good candidate for using the MongoDB "[embedded document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)" form. Part of that answer may derive from, 'I always did it that way because they told me so".

Half the point of why MongoDB exists is to provide an alternative to modeling in, "Second normal form", "Third normal form" semantics, in the case where this **makes sense** to the usage patterns and storage requirements. And generally to say that the concept of document embedding exists to **avoid** the need to fetch "related" results from *another collection* as the results are already *embedded* in the response document.

Is it better to have different Id's? You mean in different collections. Where MongoDB **does 
not do Joins**. Then the case would be probably not, but if you need it then consider the consequences.

As the wise Jedi said, "Unlearn, what you have learned". And apply a different way of thinking to your schema design, the MongoDB will suit you well.

Good luck Padawan.